# i want configure one of the column in csv file and its the value of the variable is already fetched from a config file in perl

Tags: perl, variables, csv, interpretation

I have a csv file from where I fetching the data line by line and calling the function and giving the value..
I just want one of the value in the csv file configurable so I put the $ sign
but its value is not interpreted in the program and I already added the the same value into the program so that it can take that value.

from a csv file I getting the value as:

```
1,    TC_6.01_UA_CREATE_USER    ,$create_user_command
```

this is the function:-

```
sub function{
    # $create_user_command --this is the global variable
    # that i take from the config file ;

    print "$create_user_command";
    # it is showing the command-- create user

    my $tc_name = $_[1];
    print "test case name : $tc_name\n";
    my $test_command = $_[2];
    # the value at the second index $_[2]is the value
    # from the csv file that i want to configure

    print "test case command: $test_command\n";
    # this is just simply printing the value from csv
    # i.e $create_user_command but not interpreting it
    print "$test_command\n";
}
```

I just want how to interpret that `$create_user_command` value from the csv..
please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

You way wish to use eval.

perldoc -f eval

[perldoc eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)

Use eval with care, it will run arbitrary code and can bite you very badly.
Check that the value of $create_user_command is something you understand
and not something like:

```
$create_user_command = "qx(rm -rf /)";  # BAD
```